# Does the Howling Abyss map (ARAM map) use an MMR rating system?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know normal, Dominion, and the ranked modes all use an MMR rating to pair you up with equally skilled opponents. Is that the case for the new Howling Abyss map?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does, as it also has its own win/lose counter. I can't really prove it though :)

Comment: I was thinking that too, but I'm not sure myself, haha.

Comment: I've been waiting for ARAM to get it's own rating system :3 that would be awesome.

Comment: I also can't prove it but TT, SR, and Dom all have rating systems. I am consistently against gold and platinum players in TT so that says something. I'm not sure how it's shared with SR and Dom though.

Comment: Its worth noting that riot is thinking about making ranked for HA due to its immediate popularity with players(its had more games played since its release than dominion had within its first year). So it will definitely have a hidden MMR.

Comment: Where did you get that information?

Comment: I don't have a source for the information on a site. My friend keeps up on things going on within the LoL community. I'm not sying that it does or doesn't have a built in hidden mmr at the moment, but if Riot does end up bringing forth a ranked version of ARAM it will most definitely have a hidden MMR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

[Source: Riot Pwyff](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3389328#37217054)

> I know we have separate MMRs per map. I believe HA will have a new
>   hidden MMR specifically for it but we get that ARAM is less about
>   precise skill matchmaking and more about SUPER RANDOM CHAOS. So the
>   focus is on light balance and more on getting you matches in the queue
>   faster.

[Source: Super Nomegeta](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=3227955#35634755)

> It'll have its own hidden normal Elo, but be based on your SR normal
>   Elo initially.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. I played a game as an experience player and watch my team peel for for the adc or apc and when I watched a game of a lower aram game they just do whatever they want. Although there are cases that you get paired with someone not of your MMR. I had an anivia who keeps blaming team mates while she is 4-15.